# Based on "tap" how do I access timer object and stop processing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, nstimer

Yes, another newbie question - process/workflow question.  Please be patient.

I've got a NSTimer object, timer, created in one method methA, being passed to another method methB where it's used to contorl some processing.  Both methods are within the same class.

I have touchesBegin and touchesEnded methods to capture user input.  These methods are in the same class as my two previous methods - methA and methB.  When a user "taps" on my screen I need to stop processing

When my touchesBegin method is invoked by a tap I'm assuming all I have to do is send a message to my other methods, methA/methB, and tell them to stop processing.  I'm assuming all I have to do is invalidate the timer that's being passed to my "processing" method, i.e. methB.

Does this sound right?  I've included my four methods touchesBegin, methA, and methB.  Any input is greatly appreciated.

```
- (void) methA
{

    stepValue = 0;
    animationBuild = YES;

    float duration = [[[Config shared] valueForKey:@"animation.val.step_duration"] floatValue];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:duration target:self selector:@selector(stepValue:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 

} 

- (void) methB:(NSTimer *) timer
{
    if (animationBuild)
    {
        // animation logic/processing
    }

    // Next step
    stepValue++;

    if (stepValue == GROUP_SIZE)
    {
        [timer invalidate];

        [self animateShowMessage];

    }
}


- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    if (modalDialog)
    {
        return;        
    }

    if (currentTouch == nil)
    {
        UITouch *touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];

        currentTouch = [touch retain];
    }
}


- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    if (modalDialog)
    {
        return;        
    }

    UITouch *touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];

    if ((touch != nil) && (touch == currentTouch))
    {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

        else if ((CGRectContainsPoint(visRect[[Process shared].procType], point)) && (touch.tapCount == 2))
            {            
                // processing
            }

        else
        {
            // Start a new processing
            [self startNew];
        }

        [currentTouch release];
        currentTouch = nil;        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's essentially correct, however, I would make a couple of design changes.

Unless you are building for pre-iOS 3.x app, you should be using a `UIGestureRecognizer` to recognize taps, not the older touchesBegan approach. Using a recognizer is very easy:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = 
   [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                    action:@selector(handleTap:)] autorelease];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

I typically don't like to have more than one place in my code that I modify a timer. If you have timer modification scattered throughout code, you are likely to miss an invalidation or release somewhere. So, I usually create a timer property like the example below. If you use a property like this, changing your timer object or setting your timer to nil will automatically invalidate it, so its guaranteed to never be in a funky state.

```
- (void)setTimer:(NSTimer *)newTimer {
    [_timer invalidate];
    [newTimer retain];
    [_timer release];
    _timer = newTimer;
}
```